# Drawing spheres with mouse positions in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to draw spheres at the mouse locations everytime I click the screen.

I wrote a function to get the 3D mouse coordinates, everytime the mouse is clicked. It works like a charm.

Now how can I create spheres at those locations.

```
void display()
{
...
...
glColor3f(1,0,0)
glutWireSphere(3,100,100);
glTranslatef(X,Y,Z);
}

void MouseFunc()//where the 3D mouse coordinates are recieved
{
double X,Y,Z// where I store the coordinates.
.....
.....
glutDisplayFunc(display);//Because thats where I create the spheres
}
```

Comment: Side note: `glut` is quite old and actually not very good. Try [SDL](http://libsdl.org/), you won't regret it.

Comment: @Shahbaz: FreeGLUT is actively maintained. And if you're focussing on OpenGL, then GLFW is actually the (IMHO) better windowing and input event management framework.

Comment: @Shahbaz: For a beginner, glut will be much easier to deal with than SDL, and they focus on different things. SDL doesn't provide geometry primitives, and tries to act as if it were DirectDraw (by providing software surfaces, etc).

Comment: @sigterm, perhaps, but all you need with SDL is open an OpenGL window and you're set. Event handling is much easier with SDL since you have more control. Most importantly though, glut doesn't take/pass a `void *` argument to its callbacks. That means you are either bound to have everything in one file (and use `static` variables) or use global variables which leads to other problems.

Comment: @Shahbaz: (opinion) glut makes shortest beginner programs, compared to sdl (/opinion). Regarding `void*`... glut window have integer ids. You can get id of current window, and receive id when you create current window. So if you have to pass some data to glut window, you can careate a map somewhere that'll map ids to window data, and that's all you ever need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MouseFunc store the position of the click into a array/list/vector visible to the drawing function, i.e. not in locally scoped variable. Then you call `glutPostRedisplay` to make GLUT call the display func you registered **once** in the initialization code using `glutDisplayFunc`.

In the display function itself you iterate over the array/list/vector and draw a sphere for each element according to the element's data.

#### Code sample due to request in comment

clicksphere.cc

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <list>

typedef union v2f_t {
    struct {
        float x;
        float y;
    };
    float v[2];
} v2f_t;

typedef std::list<v2f_t> v2flist_t;

v2flist_t sphere_centers;

void display(void)
{
      int const window_width  = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
      int const window_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    float const window_aspect = (float)window_width / (float)window_height;

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if(window_aspect > 1.) {
        glOrtho(-window_aspect, window_aspect, -1, 1, -1, 1);
    }
    else {
        glOrtho(-1, 1, -1/window_aspect, 1/window_aspect, -1, 1);
    }
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLfloat const light_pos[4]     = {-1.00,  1.00,  1.00, 0.};
    GLfloat const light_color[4]   = { 0.85,  0.90,  0.70, 1.};
    GLfloat const light_ambient[4] = { 0.10,  0.10,  0.30, 1.};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_pos),
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_color);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
    
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    for( v2flist_t::iterator sc = sphere_centers.begin();
         sc != sphere_centers.end();
         sc++ ) {

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(sc->x, sc->y, 0);
        glutSolidSphere(0.1, 31, 10);
        glPopMatrix();
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mouseclick(
    int button,
    int state,
    int mouse_x,
    int mouse_y )
{
      int const window_width  = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
      int const window_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    float const window_aspect = (float)window_width / (float)window_height;

    v2f_t const sc = {
        (window_aspect > 1.0 ? window_aspect : 1.) *
        (  ((float)mouse_x / (float)window_width )*2. - 1.),

        (window_aspect < 1.0 ? 1./window_aspect : 1.) *
        ( -((float)mouse_y / (float)window_height)*2. + 1.)
    };
    sphere_centers.push_back(sc);

    glutPostRedisplay();
}


int main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[] )
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    
    glutCreateWindow("Click to place spheres");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouseclick);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But can you give an example?

Comment: thanks figured it out. What would be a good library to use for quaternion slerp?

Comment: GLM or Eigen; or my [linmath.h](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h/blob/master/linmath.h), but I don't know "how good" it actually is. It's up to other people to judge my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create the transformation matrix, then draw. In other words:

```
glTranslatef(X,Y,Z);       /* everything from here below would be translated */
glutWireSphere(3,100,100); /* draw with the current transformation matrix */
```